# How to read multiple excel files in Different Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, excel, pandas, list, dataframe

I have collection of excel files containing similar datasets. I want it to be read by different Pandas dataframes.

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

path=r"C:users/me/desktop/ExcelData"

files=glob.glob('*.xls')
for f in files:
      df[f]=pd.read_excel(f)
```

Comment: create a list(say `lst=[]`) outside the for loop and then append your dataframe in it.....then access your dataframe by `lst[0]`,`lst[1]`.....so where you stucked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import glob
import pandas as pd
import os

path=r"C:\\users\\me\\desktop\\ExcelData\\"
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.xls"))

dfl=[]
for f in csv_files:
    x= pd.read_excel(f)
    dfl.append(x)
```

Comment: I executed the code. However, df_list is empty. Please note that 'files' variable is non-empty and contains 80 xls files

Comment: made an edit! make sure that you are able to read the data into your code(made changes to the file path as per windows)

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

path = r"C:users/me/desktop/ExcelData"
files = glob.glob(path + "\*.xls")

finalexcelsheet = pd.DataFrame()

for file in files:
    df = pd.concat(pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = None), ignore_index=True, 
    sort=False)
    finalexcelsheet = finalexcelsheet.append(df, ignore_index = True)

print(finalexcelsheet)
```

Comment: Ultimately, I wanted Excel output, but not this way. It creates many NaN values. In between different Pandas operations are involved. Now I am done. Math operations, Dataframe operations including horizontal concat are involved.

Comment: for this solution, I assumed that all the Data Frames had the same columns. If this is that is the case the code will work smoothly.